# How is example performance calculated

Tags: pymodbus

I'm new to Modbus and particularly pymodbus and as I came across the performance comparison between the sync (11.41 ms/reg) and async interfaces (0.03 ms/reg) (we plan to use the latter) I was curious how the performance was computed?  Is this based on using the simulator which provides data at TCP speeds or the like?   Trying to understand the numbers such as 0.03 ms/register at the settings of 9600 baud (0.1 ms/bit).  I'm assuming these numbers are computed based on (clock time) - (theoretical HW maximum) for both interfaces although the printouts seem to have come from the example.

When I run a simple calculation ignoring protocol overhead, stop bits, etc. there's 16 bits/reg * 104 us / bit = 1.7 ms / register.